# Screen fails to turn on after sleep

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, sleep, hibernate, dell-inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron 1525 loaded with Windows 7 Professional.  When I press my button to go into sleep mode (and I'm positive I'm going into sleep mode, I've checked the battery settings), I can only return from sleep mode after a brief period of time. If I try to resume Windows after some period of time, my screen fails to turn on. This problem happened with my Windows Vista Home Premium. This leads me to believe that it is a problem with the Laptop itself. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try a new bios upgrade. i have a 1420 and had the same problem untill i upgraded the bios to the latest

Comment: also remember get your lastest video drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike's comment was correct. Going to the [Dell](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/) downloads center and upgrading my BIOS fixed the problem.